# What should to do to import data to mysql from mongodb via PHP MongoDB Driver?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel

There is an example in docs of PHP MongoDB Driver(http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-cursor.toarray.php) ,
the example code as follow:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulk->insert(['x' => 1]);
$bulk->insert(['x' => 2]);
$bulk->insert(['x' => 3]);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.collection', $bulk);

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([]);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('db.collection', $query);

var_dump($cursor->toArray());
```

**Question:**

I want to insert `$cursor` into mysql,what should I do to it? `toArray()` can change it into an array,but the elements of the array are `BSONDocument`s,they can not be insert mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to loop over your array of BSON objects, and insert them to a MySQL table with the same fields. You can use a PDO prepared statement for this, and execute it with values from each respective BSON.

```
$pdoStmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO MyTable SET x = :x");

foreach ($cursor->toArray() as $bson) {
  $data = get_object_vars($bson);
  unset($data["_id"]);
  $pdoStmt->execute($data);
}
```

But this assumes your MySQL table has exactly the same fields as your BSON document. It's likely that the best MySQL table design to be different from your MongoDB document design. These are two different paradigms for storing data.

This also assumes your BSON document has simple name-value pairs, where all values are scalars. MySQL doesn't support arrays or anything as subdocuments. This also assumes all your BSON documents have identical structure, that is, the same set of named fields in all documents.

You should learn something about relational database design before you attempt this.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `toArray` u can use `iterator_to_array` as below:

```
$resultArray = iterator_to_array($cursor);
```